# Tomcat apps fail to deploy with STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy an application on Tomcat 8.0.39 with option STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true by updating apache-tomcat-8.0.39\conf\catalina.properties but as soon as I do that my application deployment fails.
i.e. I start getting errors:
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.error Parse Error for all the tags in applications web.xml file.

One of the stack trace is as follows:

> 09-Feb-2017 15:06:32.189 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.error Parse Error at line 5 column 66: Document root element "web-app", must match DOCTYPE root "xml".
>    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Servers/Tomcat%208/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/file-service/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 66; Document root element "web-app", must match DOCTYPE root "xml".
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1448)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

For resolving that issue, I tried following options:

1) Added following in catalina.properties:

```
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false
```

2) Updated agent WAR web.xml File
Updated web-app_3_0.xsd with web-app_2_5.xsd
Updated version="3.0" with version="2.5"

I also tried copying "web-app" tag entry from apache-tomcat-8.0.39\conf\web.xml to my applications web.xml but of no use.

3) Tried setting following values to their respective default values [as setting

```
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true changes these defaults]
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.GET_RESOURCE_REQUIRE_SLASH
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.WRAP_SAME_OBJECT
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.LAST_ACCESS_AT_START
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.STRICT_NAMING

The **URIEncoding** attribute of any HTTP connector or AJP connector element.
The **resourceOnlyServlets** attribute of any Context element.
The **tldValidation** attribute of any Context element.
The **useRelativeRedirects** attribute of any Context element.
The **xmlNamespaceAware** attribute of any Context element.
The **xmlValidation** attribute of any Context element.
```

But nothing seems to be working fine. I am also not able to navigate to tomcat manager or any other application deployed.

On the other hand every thing works fine when I write STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false in catalina.properties

Is there something which I am missing here? Please help me in resolving this issue.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well.  The environment we work in requires the STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE be set to true, but the validation of the web.xml was not the driving force behind the requirement.  To get around the issue try setting the xmlValidation to false in the conf/context.xml's  tag:

```
<Context xmlValidation="false"> ... </Context>
```

Comment: I am not sure how I missed to answer this question of mine, but yes we fixed this issue long back using the option which you have mentioned. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Below will address this issue

catalina.properties

org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false